# Error when trying to load Django custom filters into template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I've inherited a Django application that I need to modify using a custom template filter. I'm absolutely new to Django and am quite mystified by it. I thought I had followed the instructions exactly, and also followed all the advice from other posts on the subject, but I still get an error when I include the following line in my template:

```
{% load mlgb_custom_filters %}
```

My directory structure is as follows:

```
mysite (i.e. the project)    
    __init__.py    
    mlgb/ (i.e. the app)    
      __init__.py    
      templatetags/    
          __init__.py    
          mlgb_custom_filters.py
```

The code of mlgb_custom_filters.py is as follows:

```
from django import template    
from django.template.defaultfilters import stringfilter    
register = template.Library()    
@register.filter(name='fix_dashes')    
@stringfilter    
def fix_dashes( value ):    
    return value.replace( '--', 'DASH' )    
if __name__ == "__main__":    
    testvar = fix_dashes( "ouch -- ow -- I hate django" )    
    print testvar
```

As you can see, I've added a 'name = main' section to let me run it in standalone mode, just to check that there are no errors in that particular file, and it's fine when run in standalone mode.

Based on someone else's advice, I've also tried importing it into another file, just to see whether there was an import error, and once again, it was fine if I added this to the end of settings.py (while using the dev server):

try:
    import mlgb.templatetags.mlgb_custom_filters
except Exception, exc:
    print 'error importing mlgb_custom_filters'
    print exc

Also, INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py includes the line 'mysite.mlgb', and I have also tried putting just 'mlgb' instead of 'mysite.mlgb' there, as yet another person suggested. And I restarted the dev server every time I made a change.

I think I have tried every single suggestion that I have found on the web until now. Does anyone have any new ideas? Could it be anything to do with the fact that I have inherited a directory structure where the template directory is not within the same structure as the application, i.e. it is not under mysite? Scraping the barrel for ideas here! I hope someone can help.

Comment: hi, the dev server gives me these errors beginning with:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 280, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 674, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 241, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 141, in get_response

Comment: better to put the error in the question

Comment: yay half an traceback.  Just what I always wanted.  And not even the exception type nor does the posted trackback hit a single line in your project!  Totally debuggable.

Comment: @SueB.: if you have a traceback always post it in entirety in your question. Never just say, "I got an error". That doesn't tell anyone anything.

Answer (score 2):

OK, in the situation that I was in when first posting this question, it seems all I actually needed to do was touch a `wsgi` file under my `appname/apache` directory to force the application to be refreshed. Yesterday's initial answer was a red herring. Basically I should have touched the file `myproject/myapp/apache/myapp.wsgi`. Then maybe restart Apache for good measure? But the confusion was caused by the fact that apparently it wasn't enough either simply to restart Apache or to manually recompile the Python. In order to pick up my changes, seems like I needed to touch that wsgi file. Then all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I can now post an answer to my own question thanks to the help of my colleague Masud Khokhar, whose brilliant detective work has saved the day. To recap, my application worked fine until I added a 'load' statement to one of my template files, to load a 'custom filters' module. Masud identified that now I needed to use a full/absolute path to the template file in urls.py instead of a relative one as I had before (and which worked before, until it needed to load the custom filters module). So, in urls.py, I had a section of code as follows:

```
 url(r'^book/(?P<object_id>\d+)/$', 'list_detail.object_detail',
     kwargs={
        'queryset':Book.objects.all(),
        'template_name' : 'mlgb/mlgb_detail.html'
     },
     name='mlgb_detail'
 ),
```

Instead of this:

```
        'template_name' : 'mlgb/mlgb_detail.html'
```

I needed something like this:

```
        'template_name' : '/THE_FULL_PATH/mlgb/templates/mlgb/mlgb_detail.html'
```

Made that change - sorted! Thank you once again, Masud.

Comment: Masud also suggested that instead of hard-coding the path to the template file, I should use os.path to generate it from the relative path instead. In the end, I used the value of TEMPLATE_DIRS from settings.py, i.e. `'template_name' : '%smlgb/mlgb_detail.html' % settings.TEMPLATE_DIRS`

Comment: Actually it turns out I didn't need to do all that changing of paths. Just needed to make sure that my changes to .py files were getting picked up. Had already tried deleting .pyc files and manually recompiling, plus restarting apache, with no joy. But then finally did that "touch the wsgi file" which people had mentioned in other posts. Initially my problem was that I had no idea where this wsgi file lived! Finally I found it. My project is under a directory called 'mysite' and under that I have an app called 'mlgb'. File I had to touch was under /mysite/mlgb/apache and was called mlgb.wsgi.